# How to return a similar match in the same 2d list

Tags: python, dataframe, list, multidimensional-array, jupyter-notebook

I have a 2d list that Im trying to return more than 2 matches in each sublist and any column in the same 2d list if that makes sense. Then I would like to remove the duplicates in 2d list. If possible.
Here is my 2d list below.

```
Df = [[2,4,6,8],[2,4,6,12,15], 
[2,4,8,17,24],[3,7,17,24], 
[5,10,15,23],[8,10,43], 
[4,5,10,55],[4,8,15,16,17,56]]
```

Match from Df

```
Df2 = [[[2,4,6,8], 
[2,4,6,12,15],[2,4,8,17,24]],
[[[2,4,6,8],[2,4,8,17,24]], 
[[[2,4,6,8]], 
[[[4,8,15,16,17,24]]]
```

Remove the duplicates for df2

```
 Df3 = [[2,4,6,8], 
 [2,4,6,12,15],[2,4,8,17,24], 
 [4,8,15,16,17,24]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest with `Df`, return the sublists that have more than 2 elements in common and then remove the duplicates from the second list DF2.

**Finally then display the results**.

```
Df = [[2,4,6,8],[2,4,6,12,15], 
[2,4,8,17,24],[3,7,17,24], 
[5,10,15,23],[8,10,43], 
[4,5,10,55],[4,8,15,16,17,56]]

def has_common_elements(list1, list2):
    return len(set(list1) & set(list2)) > 2

result = []
for sublist in Df:
    if any(has_common_elements(sublist, other) for other in Df if sublist != other) and sublist not in result:
        result.append(sublist)

print("Result from Df:", result)

Df2 = [[[2,4,6,8], [2,4,6,12,15],[2,4,8,17,24]],
[[2,4,6,8],[2,4,8,17,24]], 
[[2,4,6,8]], 
[[4,8,15,16,17,24]]]

def flatten(lst):
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            yield from flatten(item)
        else:
            yield item

flattened = list(flatten(Df2))
chunks = [flattened[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(flattened), 4)]
unique_df2 = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(sorted(sublist)) for sublist in chunks if len(sublist) == 4)]

print("Unique values from Df2:", unique_df2)
```

Comment: Got an error invalid syntak def flatten(lst):